# Spring Data Mongo: How to return nested object by its field?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have domain:

```
class Company {
    List<Job> jobs;
}
```

Is there a way to return nested object from collection like:

```
@Repository
public interface CompanyRepository extends MongoRepository<Company, String>{
    Job findByJobId(String jobId);
}
```

Comment: Regarding spring mongo repository documentation and even to spring data repositories core concept description, using Repository interface gives you ability to work with doman type as a whole. If you want to access an embedded field, I suggest using MongoOperations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have to make some assumptions about the structure of your `Job` model, but assuming something like this:

```
public class Job {
    private String id;
    // other attributes and methods
}
```

... and assuming that this model is embedded in your `Company` model, and not represented in another collection, you will have to go the custom implementation via `MongoTemplate` route.  The Spring Data query API is not going to be able to figure out how to get what you want, so you must implement the method yourself.

```
@Repository
public interface CompanyRepository extends CompanyOperations, MongoRepository<Company, String>{
} 

public interface CompanyOperations {
    Job findByJobId(String jobId);
}

public class CompanyRepositoryImpl implements CompanyOperations {
    @Autowired private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Override
    public Job findByJobId(String jobId){
        Company company = mongoTemplate.findOne(new Query(Criteria.where("jobs.id").is(jobId)), Company.class);
        return company.getJobById(jobId); //implement this method in `Company` and save yourself some trouble.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Yes it is possible, try this:

**Company.class**

```
@Document
public class Company {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Field("name")
    private String Name;

    @DBRef
    List<Job> job;

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

**Job.class**

```
@Document
public class Job {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Field("name")
    private String name;

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

**CompanyRepository.class**

```
public interface CompanyRepository extends MongoRepository<Company, String> {

    Company findOneByJobId(String id);

    List<Company> findByJobId(String id);
}
```

**JobRepository.class**

```
public interface JobRepository extends MongoRepository<Job, String>{

    Job findOneByName(String name);

}
```

Then you can `@Autowire` the repositories and invoke the methods:

```
Job java = new Job("Core Java Developer");
Job spring = new Job("Spring Web Developer");
Job cSharp = new Job("C# Developer");
Job dotNet = new Job(".Net Web Developer");
List<Job> allJobs = Arrays.asList(java,cSharp,spring, dotNet);
// Save All Jobs
jobRepository.save(allJobs);

// Create Companies
Company oracle = new Company("Oracle", Arrays.asList(java));
Company microsoft = new Company("Microsoft", Arrays.asList(cSharp, dotNet));
Company pivotal = new Company("Pivotal", Arrays.asList(java, spring));
// Save all companies
companyRepository.save(Arrays.asList(oracle,microsoft,pivotal));

// Find job by name - C#
Job cSharpJob = jobRepository.findOneByName("C# Developer");
System.out.println("*******************Found Job by Name************************");
System.out.println(cSharpJob);
System.out.println("*******************************************");

// Find One Company having Job with Job Id - C#
Company companyWithcSharpJob = companyRepository.findOneByJobId(cSharpJob.getId());
System.out.println("********************Company having C# Job found using Job Id: "+ cSharpJob.getId() +"***********************");
System.out.println(companyWithcSharpJob.getName());
System.out.println("*******************************************");
```

> Checkout the [Complete Project](https://github.com/RawSanj/SOFRepos/tree/master/SpringDataMongo) in my GitHub repository.

Comment: Thanks @Sanjay Rawat. @ DBRef helped a lot

Comment: You really saved me!!!! @Field helped me a lot. Thanks a lot mate.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use @Query annotation for return the data on the basis of nested object field.
`@Repository public interface CompanyRepository extends MongoRepository<Company, String>{ @Query("{'jobs.$jobId' : ?0}") List<Job> findCompanyByJobId(String jobId);}`