# Spring Data Mongo - bring paginated data without embedded document

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I went through many links like [Spring Data Mongo: How to return nested object by its field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39933469/spring-data-mongo-how-to-return-nested-object-by-its-field). I am using **Spring Boot v2.2.2.RELEASE + Spring Data Mongo** example.

I want to get all employees with Paginated data, but I don't want to bring the Departments.

What would I need to change in `Page<Employee> findAll(Pageable pageable)`?

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e4143762d8c210ff48f1026"),
    "firstName" : "John",
    "lastName" : "Doe",
    .....
    ......
    ......
    .......
    "departments" : [ 
        {
            "departmentName" : "IT Department",
            "departmentCode" : "IT",
            ....
            ....
        }, 
         ....
         ....
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it using below Query of `Spring Data Mongo`.

```
@Query(value = "{}", fields = "{'departments': 0}")
Page<Employee> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```