# How to write a mongo jpa query to search by inner document id?

Tags: java, sql, mongodb, spring-boot, jpa

I am new to mongo DB with JPA. I have a document object like below:

```
{
'_id': ObjectId("A"),
customer:[
    0: {
        id: 21,
        order:
            {
              id:23, 
              orderName:'orderName1'
            }
       
    },
    1: {
        id: 22,
        order:
            {
               id:12,
               orderName:'Electronics'
            }
    },
]
}
```

Here I want to get all the orders with `orderName` starting with `"Ele"`(example). I've tried:

1. `@Query(value="{'order.orderName':{'$regex':'?0','$options':'i'}}")`
2. `@Query("{'order':{'orderName':{'$regex':'?0','$options':'i'}}}")`

None of these has worked for me.

Please suggest how to do this.

Comment: Check this [asnwer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39933469/spring-data-mongo-how-to-return-nested-object-by-its-field)

Answer (score 1):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/k8Au7Bnmkvg

[$regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/)

```
db.collection.find({
  "customer.order.orderName": {
    "$regex": "Ele.+",
    "$options": "i"
  }
})
```

you're trying to query `order.orderName` but as per your schema it's inside the `customer` object so use `customer.order.orderName`